# How can we select suggestion on tab key instead of Enter key in mat-autocomplete angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

As **MatAutocomplete** (Angular 6) has default behavior of **`keydown`** and **`keyup`** for option selection and **`Enter`** for the input value of selection.

I want to use `tab` instead of `enter` key.

Please suggest

Code:

```
<input matInput [matAutocomplete]="origin">
<i class="material-icons search-form-icon">place</i>

<mat-autocomplete #origin="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let v of originList" [value]="v.value"> {{v.text}} </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [MatAutocompleteTrigger](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocompleteTrigger) documentation for details on how this trigger works and the observables it provides.

**Solution:**

Set a ChildView property in your component that is this MatAutocompleteTrigger from your template.

```
@ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger, {static: false}) trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

Subscribe to panelClosingActions on this trigger property in AfterViewInit lifecycle hook. Set the FormControl value to the activeValue of the trigger value.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.trigger.panelClosingActions.subscribe(() => {
        myControl.setValue(this.trigger.activeOption.value);
    });
}
```

Add null checks as appropriate.

Comment: I'm missing the part how to connect this viewChild in the html. Somehow trigger stays undefined for me. Did you add a #tag on the autocomplete template in html somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the original solution:

Put this in your typescript class: (you can change the name 'playlistAutocomplete' to whatever you need, just update it in html template as well!)

```
@ViewChild('playlistAutocomplete', {static: false, read: MatAutocompleteTrigger}) trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

Now in the html template you need to put a #tag on your input element. Note the second line where I put the #playlistAutocomplete:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="playlistId" #playlistAutocomplete>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption [displayWith]="showSelected">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let playlist of playlistsFiltered" [value]="playlist.id">
      <span>{{playlist.name}}</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

With this method you can directly connect your trigger to the element you want. (No magically lookup by class which fails when you have multiple such fields)

Also in your typescript class you can now get informed when the panel of the autocomplete field is closed:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.trigger.panelClosingActions.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('panelClosingAction', this.trigger.activeOption?.value);
    myControl.setValue(this.trigger.activeOption.value);
  });
}
```